# Loss in PyTorch Model is not decreasing, but it's decreasing for Keras

Tags: keras, deep-learning, nlp, pytorch, lstm

I am new to PyTorch. I want to replicate a result of Keras in PyTorch.

PyTorch Implementation:

```
class ENCODER_RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size):
        super(ENCODER_RNN, self).__init__()
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.gru = nn.GRU(hidden_size, hidden_size, num_layers=2, batch_first=True)
        self.linear_layer_1 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.linear_out = nn.Linear(hidden_size, input_size)
        
    def forward(self, input_vector, hidden_state=None):
        embed_input = self.embedding(input_vector)
        output, hidden = self.gru(embed_input, hidden_state)
        output = F.relu(self.linear_layer_1(output))
        output = F.softmax(self.linear_out(output[:,2]), dim=1)
        return output, hidden
```

```
encoder_optimizer.zero_grad()
train_tensor = torch.tensor(train_input, device=DEVICE)
output_tensor = torch.tensor(output, device=DEVICE)
hidden = None
loss = 0
output, hidden = encoder(train_tensor, hidden)
loss += criterion(output, output_tensor)
loss.backward()
encoder_optimizer.step()
```

I have assumed `hidden size = 512`.

Keras Implementation:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 50, input_length=seq_length))
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax'))
print(model.summary())
```

`input_size = vocab_size = 10437`.

I am training the same two models on the same dataset taking the same batch length. Loss for Keras model is decreasing in nature, but PyTorch model's loss is not decreasing. Moreover it's oscillating in nature.

Please help me out here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you call `output[:,2]` in the output of your class? Is your sequences of length 3? Why don't you use `hidden` instead? It's what you're doing in the keras code.

Comment: @jhso yes, my sequence length is 3. But why do I use  `hidden`? I am comparing the final output to the target value.

Comment: `hidden` is the final cell state of your model, so in GRU I guess it is the same thing. Also, you are not comparing the same models. Your hidden size is different, and your embedding in your keras model is only 50-sized.  Also, try reducing your output before the first linear layer, not afterwards.